# Optionally pass through a single view parameter in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Consider this scenario where I want to SOMETIMES pass data through to my view:

```
public function show($orderId)
{
    if ($sometimesTrue == true)
    {
        $optionalParameter = 'optional parameter';
    }

    return view('show', compact([$a, $b, $c, $optionalParameter]));
}
```

`$optionalParameter` is not always set, so I want to know what my options are for setting individual, optional view parameters without re-arranging the structure of the function.

In Zend, the following is possible:

```
$this->view->optionalParameter = $optionalParameter;
```

Which can go anywhere in the controller method, not just at the end where the `view` is instantiated. Of course, back in Laravel, I could do something this:

```
public function show($orderId)
{
    $paramaterArray = [$a, $b, $c];

    if ($sometimesTrue == true)
    {
        $optionalParameter = 'optional parameter';
        $paramaterArray[] = $optionalParameter;
    }

    return view('show', compact($paramaterArray));
}
```

But re-arranging entire functions because a optional parameter is introduced seems a bit limiting. Is there any way I can set an individual parameter for a view?

Answer (score 0):

You can just built your own `protected function` + `protected property` in the `Controller` class. You could do something like this:

Beneath is using the splat operator so it will only work in php 5.6 >=

```
protected $optionalParameter;

protected function optionalcompact(...$parameters) {
    if(!empty($this->optionalParameter)){
        return compact($parameters, $this->optionalParameter);
    } else {
        return compact($parameters);
    }
}
```

Then back in your own built controller class you can do this:

```
public function show($orderId)
{    
    if ($sometimesTrue == true)
    {
        $this->optionalParameter = 'optional parameter';
    }

    return view('show', $this->optionalcompact($a, $b, $c));
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I like how it keeps the structure of the function the same. It would only allow for one optional parameter per function though (easily circumnavigated, of course). Let's see what else people come back with. I was hoping for something native to Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use the following

```
public function show($orderId)
{
    $paramaterArray = [$a, $b, $c];

    $paramaterArray['optional'] = $sometimesTrue == true ? 'optional parameter' : '';

    return view('show', $paramaterArray);
}
```

Since this is an optional parameter so I don't need to check every time in my view whether it's set or not, simply `{{ $optional }}` will work better, it'll be printed if any value is set or nothing will be printed if the `$optional` variable is empty. This way, I'll remain consistant.

Also, you may check the Larave's [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers), it may help you.

Comment: Cheers for this. I was hoping to avoid refactoring existing controller methods to add a single optional parameter though.

Comment: This however will still send an empty variable to the view.

Comment: Yes, which is consistant, now extra code to check for availability.

Answer (score 0):

Researching further, it seems that using `compact` with the names of the variables (as opposed to the variables themselves) will silently ignore the missing variable which gives the intended behaviour:

```
$var1 = 'bob';
$var2 = 'nigel';

var_dump(compact('var1', 'var2', 'var3'));
```

Returns:

```
array(2) { ["var1"]=> string(3) "bob" ["var2"]=> string(5) "nigel" }
```

Which works perfectly for my scenario. Using it this way, the controller method doesn't require refactoring and no additional coding is required. Whether relying on `compact` to not issue a warning is good coding practice is another question.

Just to confirm, calling `compact` with the variables themselves WILL throw a `notice` warning:

```
$var1 = 'bob';
$var2 = 'nigel';

var_dump(compact($var1, $var2, $var3));
```

Returns:

```
NOTICE Undefined variable: var3 on line number 4
```